# Android apps developement using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How to develop an android application in Eclipse? While updating eclipse there is some problems...

Comment: Use the [ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely start here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

That's a great beginning that covers downloading Eclipse, installing the SDK, downloading and installing required Android platforms, and has some how-to's and "Hello World" app tutorials.

If you're just looking to install the SDK for Eclipse and all of the steps involved with that, this link is what you'll need:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Good luck!